# How to echo inside onclick echoed link in PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink, echo

I have a working button to add a new instrument by calling the detailed instrument lab and code data from the Mysql database using attr_lab_code and id_ins_code.  Below is the working code

```
<button class=" button" style="vertical-align:middle" onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url() . 'in/' . $ao->attr_lab_code . '/' . $ao->id_ins_code . '/add' ?>';"><span>Add new instrument</span></button>
```

The output will be http://base_url/in/labcode/inscode/add

I want to add a condition that will disable the button in January and December. The disable button (for January and December) is working but I can't get the button working for other conditions (for February to November). I still have a problem putting the original button link on the new echo button. This is the code :

```
<?php $month = date('m'); 
if ($month == 1 or $month == 12) { 
echo "<button style='vertical-align:middle' class='button' disabled>Add new instrument</></button></br><p>Add new instrument is <em>not-active.</em>  "; } 
else { 
echo "<button class='button' style='vertical-align:middle' href='<?php echo base_url() . '/in/' . $ao->attr_lab_code . '/' . $ao->id_ins_code . '/add' ?><span>Add new instrument</span></button> "; } 
?>
```

I am new to PHP, so I am still getting confused about this.
What should I change to make the code work on the else condition? The created link based on the original button should be: http://base_url/in/labcode/inscode/add
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Simply close the PHP tag after { and open it back before } and use exactly the same code you had

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part should I edit?